# How to set the relative layout to move based on the Default keyboard appearance and disappearance?

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

This is the Screen Shot of my View:
[image]

Here Previous, Reply and Next button is on the RelativeLayout. Right now i have set the Topmargin of that relativelayout. I want to set as like if the default keyboard is apper then that layout should be on the uper side of the keyboard, and if the keyboard is disapper then that layout should be goes to the Bottom of the Screen.

the Code for that view is as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/returnToSoundTest"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:text="Sound Test"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/glossy_button_blank_black_rectangle"
        >
    </Button>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:text="test_name"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="28dip"
        >
    </TextView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:text="Exit"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/glossy_button_blank_black_rectangle"
        >
    </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
<!-- Header Part End -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dip">
<!-- ++++++++++++++ EXTRA BUTTON +++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
            <com.quiz.spellingquiz.MyButton
                    android:id="@+id/deleteall"
                    android:layout_width="80dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Deleteall"
                    android:textSize="22dip"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"

                    android:background="@drawable/btn_home_continue"/>


            <com.quiz.spellingquiz.MyButton
                    android:id="@+id/showall"
                    android:layout_width="80dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Show all"
                    android:textSize="22dip"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_home_continue"/>
        <!-- ++++++++++++++ EXTRA BUTTON +++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/mainPart"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dip"
        android:padding="15dip">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/enter_word_text"
                    android:text="Enter word"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="22dip"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/question_number"
                    android:text="Question of "
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="22dip"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"/>
            </RelativeLayout>   

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/answer_word"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:hint="test word"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
                android:textSize="15dip">
                </EditText> 
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>         

    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:background="@drawable/header_gradient"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainPart">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:text="Previous"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/glossy_button_blank_black_rectangle"
            >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/replay"
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:text="Replay"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/previous"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/glossy_button_blank_black_rectangle"
            >
        </Button>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextEvaluate"
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/glossy_button_blank_black_rectangle"
            >
        </Button>

</RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

So, now What changes i have to do to acheave such type of view appearance ?
Please help me regarding this.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, i have tried more but not able to put whole code here. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try this by adding this tag under Activity tag in manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|adjustResize"
```

Comment: ummm its works but there is one problem. it Resize the layout so the backgroundImage that i have puted is get stretch. So what should i have to do for it. Please help me in this.

Comment: give some constant size to those images like "100dip" or some value.

Comment: its damage my Background image. What should i have to do for it ?

Comment: But it will affect the Screen Size. If the Screen Size got change then it will be also seen bad.

Comment: what do you mean by damage my Background image..? how can it damage your image..?

Comment: No dear, i mean the layout of Background get stretch.

Comment: i think i am doing stateAlwaysVisible|adjustResize for whole layout. but it there any other alternate to do it for only some specific layout i mean for some relativelayout like ??

Answer (score 1):

First of all,  have a id for your bottom bar. Then try adding `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` property to it. see if that works.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dip"
    android:background="@drawable/header_gradient"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainPart"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
```

Comment: i have try it. But if the keyboard is apper, then that layout goes behind the keyboard. Instead of that i want to set it to apper on the keyboardlayout.